# How to fix a non-terminal getting null from one rule to another

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-construction, bison

I'm writing a compiler and now I'm making the AST. In one rule, apparently, a non-terminal turns in NULL from a rule to another. I can't find the problem here.

I've tried debug with printf's, but I still don't see the problem. When I put one `if ($$)` in the `initval` rule, it prints so the `$$` isn't empty. However, when I put `if ($2)` in the `initarray` rule, it doesn't print. The same occurs in the array rule.

```
array: ':' initarray {$$ = $2;}
    | %empty {$$ = NULL;}
    ;

initarray: initarray initval {$$ = insert_node($1, $2);}
    | %empty { $$ = NULL; }
    ;

initval: LIT_INTEGER {$$ = make_new_node(AST_symbol, $1);}
    | LIT_FLOAT {$$ = make_new_node(AST_symbol, $1);}
    | LIT_CHAR {$$ = make_new_node(AST_symbol, $1);}
    ;
```

Comment: I solve the problem by changing the order of the non-terminals.
`initarray: initarray initval`
to
`initarray: initval initarray`

Comment: You have changed the rule from left recursive to right recursive.  In general, that's not a good idea — Yacc and Bison work best with left recursive rules.  What does your `insert_node()` function do when given a null pointer as the first argument?  It should probably simply return the second argument.  When the first argument is not null, then the second should be inserted at the end of the list.

Comment: The rules where you have `%empty` are not actually empty.  This is supposed to be used for rules that otherwise contain no material at all like `foo: | bar;` where a hard-to-see empty rule is hiding between the `:` and `|`.

Comment: When @JonathanLeffler says that Y and B work best with left-recursive rules, one of the things that may mean is that left-recursive rules in Yacc keep the Yacc stack small: reductions happen as early as possible. Right recursive rules snarf the entire right-recursive construct into the Yacc stack, and then pop it off in a cascade of reductions.  If large right-recursive phrases occur in the field, this can overwhelm a fixed-size Yacc stack.

Comment: The problem has to be elsewhere. All reductions of `initval` assign to `$$`; if `make_new_node` returns a non-null pointer, then all places where `initval` is used in other phrases should receive that in the respective positional variable. I've never seen that mechanism not work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler was right, `insert_node` was returning NULL, because `$1` is evaluated to NULL, and the function return `$1` with `$2` inserted on it.